# Always keep a parameter in URL?

Tags: debug

Is there any way that WordPress always keeps a custom parameter in every link it generates? Here's what I want to do.

I want to create a debug mode by entering `?debug` as a URL parameter; and display some specific information or do some debug only coding if that URL parameter is available. I know what I need to get WP to work with custom URL parameters. I want to know how can I make WP to keep `debug` parameter in all the liks it generates; and this parameter keeps propagating to all the links I click on while navigating the entire site until I remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not change the output you want to debug just to debug it, that’s a contradiction. :)

Use cookies for that. For example, put something like this into your `wp-config.php`:

```php
if ( ! empty ( $_GET['debug'] ) )
{
    if ( 'on' === $_GET['debug'] )
        set_debug_mode( TRUE );
    elseif ( 'off' === $_GET['debug'] )
        set_debug_mode( FALSE );
}
elseif ( isset ( $_COOKIE['debug'] ) )
{
    if ( 'on' === $_COOKIE['debug'] )
        set_debug_mode( TRUE );
    else
        set_debug_mode( FALSE );
}
else
{
    set_debug_mode( FALSE );
}

/**
 * Turn debug mode on or off.
 *
 * @param  bool $on
 * @return bool TRUE if cookie could be set.
 */
function set_debug_mode( $on = TRUE )
{
    if ( ! $on )
        return setcookie( 'debug', 'on', time() - 3600, '/' );

    define( 'WP_DEBUG',         TRUE );
    define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', TRUE );
    define( 'SAVEQUERIES',      TRUE );
    define( 'DIEONDBERROR',     TRUE );
    define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG',     TRUE );

    return setcookie( 'debug', 'on', time() + 604800, '/' ); // one week;
}
```

Now add `?debug=on` to any URL, and all following requests will use the debug mode. Add `?debug=off` to delete the cookie and to turn debug mode off.

Comment: Very good solution. Are the constants being defined in set_debug_mode() WordPress's? Or they're for our use only?

Comment: @aceph These are the constants WordPress will use.